# Stretching ::before element to width of screen

Tags: html, css, css-position, pseudo-element, css-calc

I'm trying to stretch the `header::before` pseudo element to the full page width in this example.

`100vw` gives the pseudo element the width of the screen, so far so good.

But the left position `left: -100%;` is pushing the pseudo element too far to the left. Is it possible to calculate the correct left position?

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background: pink;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

header::before {
  background: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  /* full page width */
  left: -100%;
  /* left positioning */
}

main {
  background: wheat;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>Header</header>
  <main>Main content</main>
</div>
```

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yZGzPO

The desired result should look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `left: calc(-50vw + 50%)` to place it across the full *viewport* width.

When you use `margin: 0 auto` it *centers* the `header` inside the wrapper. That means the width of the *empty spaces* on both sides of the `header` is 100vw minus the width of the `header`. That will be `100vw - 100%` from the *pseudo* element, and hence the viewport will start at `-(100vw - 100%) / 2`.

See demo below:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background: pink;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

header::before {
  background: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vw; /* full page width */
  left: calc(-50vw + 50%); /* left positioning */
}

main {
  background: wheat;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>Header</header>
  <main>Main content</main>
</div>
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you! It seems to be working great. Do you care to explain how your solution works?

Answer (score 1):

Make that pseudo element position from `left:calc(50% + -50vw)` and you're done!

```css
.wrapper {
 width: 70%;
 max-width: 800px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
 background: pink;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 0;
}

header::before {
 position: absolute;
 background: lightblue;
 content: "";
 z-index: -1;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100%;
 left: calc(50% + -50vw);
}

main {
 background: wheat;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <header>Header</header>
 <main>Main content</main>
</div>
```

Comment: ::before is not full width of screen

Comment: the desired output was not mentioned when i answered. Check now.

Answer (score 1):

An easier idea without bothering with calculation is to make it big enough and hide the overflow:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background: pink;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

header::before {
  content: "";
  background: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left: -100vw;
  right:-100vw;
}

main {
  background: wheat;
}

body {
 overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>Header</header>
  <main>Main content</main>
</div>
```

Comment: This was my thought first also, but I'm not too fond of the `overflow-x: hidden` value, it can cause unexpected problems down the road. However, this is a better solution if you need to have vertically scrollbars, because the accepted answer does not work with scrollable content.

Comment: @petsk yes and this is the main purpose of SO. providing different answers as there is no *better* one. Then any one can pick up the answer that works the best for him ;)

Comment: Yes, that's true :)